# Good data format to store ISO 8601 recurrence in to mysql

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I need to store ISO 8601 recurrence (something like R/20130325T06/P1D) to a table. this table stores different recurring jobs that needs to be executed.

Is there any native data type mysql (or any other db for the knowledge) that can be used to store this data other than VARCHAR data type.

Comment: There is no native datatype for this data type in SQL.

Comment: as long as you can convert it both ways, you don't need it, when you need calculation on dates and time you have to use the mysql Datatyp Date, Datetime,Timestamp

Comment: If you are simply storing and retrieving it, then `VARCHAR`.  If you need to get the date/time/etc, then you are on your own.  Nothing in MySQL understands ISO 8601.

Comment: Thanks for all the comment, we went ahead with VARCHAR for this. basically it is the store/retrieve what we are looking at